# Here nearybysearch is returning 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-places-api

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?radius=9000&key=...IzaSy...&types=car_repair&location=35.9763253,-83.89135139999999
```

I'm getting a 404 error instead of places around my coordinate.

Api reference is https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Answer (score 1):

The `output` token in the request URL needs to be replaced by the expected output data format `json` or `xml`.

See [Nearby Search requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) chapter in the API documentation.